# Rails using Google Places web API (key not working)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places address autocomplete in a rails app. 
 [I am using this example from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) and trying it out on JSFiddle works fine. I change to my API Key and then doesnt work.

I tried in my rails app in development and in production getting the same result.

As soon as i write something the text box freezes and a little 'i' appears. (not clickable)

I created and tried 'browser api key' and 'server api key' with no luck.

I set my domain as requested * .mydomain.com/* and it didnt work

I enabled
 - Google Maps JavaScript API
 - Google Static Maps API
 - Google Maps Embed API
 - Google Places API Web Service
 - Google Maps Geocoding API
 - Google Maps Geolocation API

I added to my layout/application.html.erb file

I am searching through all questions but cant find my case, please help me find a solution or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Update: In browser console i see 
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: 'mysite'

I have authorized the link exactly as shown in console but its not accepting it.

Comment: did you saw any js error on browser console?

Comment: @Francisco Do you want map..???

Comment: @Francisco  can you share the jsfiddle link..??

Comment: Thanks @power ! I am now trying to authorize a url correctly. Waiting for result to be saved. map maybe at some point, now just trying to make it work as simplest as possible.

Comment: @vishal In the google example , see where it says try it yourself. link to example in JsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Solved. 
I somehow managed to mix up my API keys in loading 1.&libraries=places and in
2.=initAutocomplete" while I was authorizing my url.

thanks to all specially to @power for reminding me to check the console logs. I know its dumb, but I keep forgetting...